# How can I serialize [native code] function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I go through the [guide](https://medium.com/@jaredloson/a-replacement-for-window-confirm-using-promises-and-react-hooks-cfc011e76a7a) on how to create the custom submit alert in React. In this guide, I must pass the "submit" function and "reject" to my file through the state manager. But, we use different state managers in react (he useContext and I redux-toolkit). So the problem is that I can't pass a function as a value to my store (all values inside must be serializable).

So I want to serialize the `reject` and the `resolve` functions and, after some time, turn them back to a normal state. But I encountered problem that when I use `response.toString()` it returns => `function () { [native code] }` and when I try to deserialize this function it returns next error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'code'
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at parseFunc (alert.ts:12:1)
    at AlertHandler (AlertHandler.tsx:28:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

My code:

```js
export const serializeFunc = (func: Function) =>
  func.toString()

export const parseFunc = (value: string) =>
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  new Function('return ' + value)()

// somewhere want to sequelize
{
  resolve: serializeFunc(resolve),
  reject: serializeFunc(reject)
}

// somewhere want to deserialize
const parsedReject = parseFunc(reject)
const parsedResolve = parseFunc(resolve)
```

The problem is that this code works with normal functions (e.g. `() => 2`). I really do not know where the problem is. Are there any possible solutions?

All code (simplified):

```js
export const serializeFunc = (func: Function) =>
  func.toString()

export const parseFunc = (value: string) =>
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  new Function('return ' + value)()

export const useConfirm = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  const Confirm = async (alert: CreateSubmitAlert) => {
    const promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject: () => void) => {
      const newAlert: IConfirmAlert = {
        ...alert,
        resolve: serializeFunc(resolve),
        reject: serializeFunc(reject)
      }
      dispatch(setAlert(newAlert))
    })

    return await promise.then(
      () => true,
      () => false
    ).finally(
      () => dispatch(closeAlert())
    )
  }

  return Confirm
}
```

My alert itself:

```js
  const alert = useAppSelector(selectAlert)

  if (alert !== undefined) {
    const {
      // ...
      reject,
      resolve
    } = alert

    const parsedReject = parseFunc(reject)
    const parsedResolve = parseFunc(resolve)

    return <>
          <Button
            onClick={() => parsedReject()}
            className={styles.button}
            buttonStyle={'ghost'}
          >
            {'Cancel'}
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => parsedResolve()}
            className={styles.button}
          >
            {confirmLabel}
          </Button>
    </>
  }
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to properly serialize a function's closure which you would need to do to here. Comparing this to `() => 2` isn't quite right, as there's nothing being closed over, whereas `reject` and `resolve` close over some promise state. Can you please provide more context on your issue, it's very odd that you'd want to serialize a promise resolver function.

Comment: I added context

Comment: Serializing a functions won't result in anything good. You should find other way

Comment: Yeah reading your code, I'm not clear why you'd want to serialize. Why not just keep a reference to the function instead of a reference to its string representation?

Comment: Reference to the function is also not serializable value(

Comment: But you can use a map with a serializable value as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably impossible to serialize this `[native code]`. So I just remake my function

```js
const promise = new Promise<AlertResult<T>>((resolve, _reject) => {
    store.dispatch(setAlert(alert))
    store.subscribe(() => {
      const result = selectAlertResult(store.getState())
      if (result !== undefined) {
        return resolve(result)
      }
    })
  })
```

I subsribe to store value changes in this function. And just return them. Now I don't store function, but value in store.